# How to list all possible combinations of traversing elements in a two dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, traversal

There is a two dimensional array in which each element is a character. From this array, a string can be generated by starting at any of the element of the array and then traverse only along the neighbors (cardinal directions) without any repetition of characters. What is the best datastructure to represent this array and what is the algorithm to generate all such possible strings out of the elements in the two dimensional array given with additional constraint that no two generated strings should be identical?

For example:
The given two dimensional array 3x3 is:
x y z 
x y z 
x y z

The possible strings generated are:(listed in alphabetical order)
x  xy  xyz  y  yx  yz  z  zy  zyx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct an undirected graph from the matrix where the nodes are the matrix elements and there is an edge between two nodes if the corresponding elements are adjacent to each other in the matrix.

Then you will have to recursively compute the paths (similar to DFS, but without keeping track of visited nodes) and keep storing the words encountered in a hash table. Keep updating the same accordingly.

Comment: A DFS won't list every path in a graph.